# Broadleaf commerce cannot integrate with Paypal express module

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, broadleaf-commerce

I have followed Broadleaf's documentation (Here is the link: http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/2.2/PayPal-Quick-Start.html) to integrate Broadleaf's DemoSite environment with Paypal express module. To implement this for development environment, I created a sandbox account and set its related value to the site.

However, when I tested my DemoSite by adding an item into my shopping cart and clicking on the Express Checkout Button, it caused my DemoSite with the following error:

```
org.broadleafcommerce.core.payment.service.exception.PaymentException: Unable to execute payment for order -- id: 1
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.payment.service.CompositePaymentServiceImpl.executePayment(CompositePaymentServiceImpl.java:69)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.payment.service.CompositePaymentServiceImpl.executePayment(CompositePaymentServiceImpl.java:74)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.payment.service.CompositePaymentServiceImpl.executePaymentForGateway(CompositePaymentServiceImpl.java:90)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.vendor.paypal.service.payment.PayPalCheckoutServiceImpl.initiateExpressCheckout(PayPalCheckoutServiceImpl.java:87)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.vendor.paypal.web.controller.BroadleafPayPalController.paypalCheckout(BroadleafPayPalController.java:84)
    at com.mycompany.controller.paypal.PayPalController.paypalCheckout(PayPalController.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.cms.web.URLHandlerFilter.doFilterInternal(URLHandlerFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.core.security.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilter(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.order.security.CartStateFilter.doFilter(CartStateFilter.java:58)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.core.security.CustomerStateFilter.doFilter(CustomerStateFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.common.security.handler.CsrfFilter.doFilter(CsrfFilter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.BroadleafRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(BroadleafRequestFilter.java:98)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1302)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1067)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1001)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:890)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:944)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.WorkflowException: org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.WorkflowException: org.broadleafcommerce.core.payment.service.exception.PaymentException: The PaymentResponseItem instance did not contain one or more of the following: transactionAmount, transactionTimestamp or transactionSuccess
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.DefaultErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:57)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.SequenceProcessor.doActivities(SequenceProcessor.java:84)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.payment.service.CompositePaymentServiceImpl.executePayment(CompositePaymentServiceImpl.java:55)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.WorkflowException: org.broadleafcommerce.core.payment.service.exception.PaymentException: The PaymentResponseItem instance did not contain one or more of the following: transactionAmount, transactionTimestamp or transactionSuccess
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.DefaultErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:57)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.SequenceProcessor.doActivities(SequenceProcessor.java:84)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.payment.service.workflow.CompositeActivity.execute(CompositeActivity.java:35)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.SequenceProcessor.doActivities(SequenceProcessor.java:75)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: org.broadleafcommerce.core.payment.service.exception.PaymentException: The PaymentResponseItem instance did not contain one or more of the following: transactionAmount, transactionTimestamp or transactionSuccess
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.payment.service.workflow.PaymentActivity.execute(PaymentActivity.java:151)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.SequenceProcessor.doActivities(SequenceProcessor.java:75)
    ... 104 more
```

Therefore, can anyone guide me how to solve the above problem. Thanks in advance.

By the way, my DemoSite is built according to Broadleaf 2.2 and Broadleaf-paypal 2.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is in the method PayPalPaymentModule.reverseAuthorize(). At the line responseItem.setAmountPaid(paymentContext.getPaymentInfo().getAmount()); it uses the deprecated method setAmountPaid(). I think there should be setTransactionAmount(). Maybe you can post that to the broadleaf forum!

I am using Broadleaf 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT and BL paypal 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

I code a workaround for this issue!

```
package de.naschkammer.payment.service.module;

import org.broadleafcommerce.core.payment.domain.PaymentResponseItem;
import org.broadleafcommerce.core.payment.service.PaymentContext;
import org.broadleafcommerce.core.payment.service.exception.PaymentException;
import org.broadleafcommerce.payment.service.module.PayPalPaymentModule;
import org.broadleafcommerce.vendor.paypal.service.payment.type.PayPalTransactionType;

// TODO remove this workaround for paypal, don't forget to adjust /site/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
public class NaschkammerPayPalPaymentModule extends PayPalPaymentModule {

    @Override
    public PaymentResponseItem authorizeAndDebit(PaymentContext paymentContext) throws PaymentException {
        PaymentResponseItem item = commonAuthorizeOrSale(paymentContext, PayPalTransactionType.AUTHORIZEANDCAPTURE);
        if ( item != null ) {
            item.setTransactionAmount(item.getAmountPaid());
        }
        return item;
    }

}
```

add following snippet to the file /site/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

```
<!-- workaround for paypal -->
<bean id="blPayPalModule" class="de.naschkammer.payment.service.module.NaschkammerPayPalPaymentModule">
    <property name="payPalPaymentService" ref="blPayPalVendorOrientedPaymentService"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are other problems that currently make the PayPal module untenable for Broadleaf version 2.3. These are outlined in the [GitHub Issues Page](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/blc-paypal/issues).

Another note: we have changed some of our versioning for the PayPal module. If you are targeting Broadleaf version 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT then you should be using PayPal version 2.4.0-SNAPSHOT (which is the 'develop' branch [on GitHub](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/blc-paypal/tree/develop).

If you have some fixes for those issues listed there, we would love for you to submit a pull request. Otherwise we will try to get a fix in for those sometime in the next week.